# PayPal Express C# Order Summary

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

How do I include line items in the order summary of PayPal Express Checkout?

I'm using ASP.Net and C# and I've tried adding this to the paypalfunctions.cs file that the PayPal Integration Wizard (`https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/`) generates, but the line item doesn't show up in the "Your Order Summary" page:

```
encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0"] = "My Line Item";
encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0"] = "1";
```

Comment: The parameter names are correct. Try to change the theme in the PayPal account configuration that uses on the order summary page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post helped solve the problem for me: [Problems with Paypal SetExpressCheckout when using NVP API in ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270718/problems-with-paypal-setexpresscheckout-when-using-nvp-api-in-asp-net)

I was also using code generated by the PayPal Wizard that sets the version to 2.3 elsewhere in the code.